# Subdomain rewrite help for joomla SEF urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, url-rewriting

been stuck at this for the past couple of hours here. Let me just illustrate my problem simply by the following lines.

Here's

1) Joomla absolute URL for the page i'm trying to convert: http://classifiedads4free.com/index.php?option=com_adsmanager&view=front

then:

Created menu item and activated SEF urls: So now alias becomes http://classifiedads4free.com/ads

after which:

I added a query string at the back of the URL so it becomes: http://classifiedads4free.com/ads?country=Singapore.

Was just wondering if there's anyway i can make the url at the top http://classifiedads4free.com/ads?country=Singapore. -->http://singapore.classifiedads4free.com

Tried going back to using the absolute URL on my .htaccess file, Following is the code:

1st tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.classifiedads4free\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.classifiedads4free\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) ads?country=%1 [L]
```

2nd tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.classifiedads4free\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.classifiedads4free\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?option=com_adsmanager&view=front&country=%1 [L]
```

However, I can't seem to get the redirect working. It keeps redirecting me back to my home page which isn't what i requested.

Would appreciate if someone could provide some assistance here. Been trying all day long.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.classifiedads4free.com/ads?country=%1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Okay. So now it works. But the URL changes as well to classifiedads4free.com/ads?country Singapore. Is there any way I can make it stay at Singapore.classifiedads4free.com?

Comment: I don't think so. Since you are rewriting to another domain name, I don't think you can do it behind the scenes like you would if you were rewriting, for example, `www.classifiedads4free.com/ads/country/singapore` to `www.classifiedads4free.com/ads?country=singapore`